# Special permutations

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations of $aaaabbbb$ appears at least a block with two $a$'s and two $b$'s in neighbor positions, as for example, $aa(aabb)bb$ or $a(baba)ba$?

I know that there exist $\frac{8!}{4!4!}=70$ permutations of $aaaabbbb$. I try a permutation of the objects $a,a, (aabb),b, b$ that are $\frac{5!}{2!2!}\times \frac{4!}{2!2!}=180$, it follows that there are some sequences counted more one time, because $180>70$. How I can count correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of "neighbor positions" such that both "aabb" and "baba" are in "neighbor positions"?  Do you just mean that there has to be a run of 4 letters where 2 are As and 2 are Bs?

Comment: I want that in each permutation of $8$ letters appear in some position at least one of the following blocks: $aabb, abab, abba, bbaa, baba, baab$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really know that are 70. But I would like use counting tecniques for get 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every arrangement of `aaaabbbb` is guaranteed to have at least one substring of four consecutive characters consisting of exactly two a's and exactly two b's.

**Proof:**

Consider the first four characters.  Either there are two a's and two b's in which case we are done, or there are more a's than b's or vice versa.  Let it be the first case.  Then either there are four a's in which case we are looking at the arrangement $aa\underline{aabb}bb$ and we are done, or we are have three a's and a b at the start.  If the second through fifth also avoids having two a's and two b's, it must be because it has at least three a's again since at least two of the second third and fourth characters are a's.  Similarly for the third through sixth etc...

This however reaches a contradiction based on the number of a's being too large since avoiding having exactly two a's and two b's by inching along like we did would imply the first through fourth have at least 3 a's and similarly the fifth through the eighth also have at least 3 a's, requiring at least 6 a's though we only had 4 available.

This makes our count exactly $\frac{8!}{4!4!}=70$